# what's the best programming language (and development community) for integer mathematics?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, integers, programming

I was wondering what's the best programming language (and development community) for integer mathematics?

I'm an R supporter. However, I'm interested in primality testing and integer factorization, including large integers.  And I'm not sure that R (and CRAN) is the best option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *Mathematica*, which has a great deal of optimized number theoretic functions built in, plus great graphics and other benefits.

Comment: Here is a list of various [computer algebra systems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) that may possibly be of some use to you

Comment: I should have mentioned that I prefer LGPL, GPL and other open source licenses.

Comment: am not an expert (like C++ myself but not sure it's especially top of class here) - have heard tell that julia is pretty good which might wrap some GNU libraries, also has something called [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/index.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic-1) which sounds promising! Again not an expert hope you get a good answer!

Comment: "best" is asking for an opinion and depends on individual factors, such as your preference for "GPL". There can be no best answer. My suggestion is PARI/GP.

Comment: Are you planning on writing these factoring algorithms yourself, or just using algorithms someone else wrote?  Are you going for fastest, or some kind of analytical results?

Comment: I've been trying to find an ultra efficient algorithm for years, and obviously, never succeeded. However, it's led to the question, if I were to succeed, what programming language should I use? I would prefer a programming language that would be appealing to others interested in this area. Presumably, such a programming language would already have some tools in this area and related areas. My understanding is that existing algorithms use some form of parallel computing, however, an ultra efficient algorithm would not require this.

Answer (score 2):

Python has had large-integer support for many years.

Also, the "Sage" mathematics environment includes many, many pre-computed things, and is based on Python.

Both are open-source, etc. Easy choice, if one has even the faintest desire to be open-source.